# Process Builder - Field Has Changed Criterion

Tags: process-builder, spring15

I am having trouble locating any sort of `HASCHANGED` function in the Process Builder criteria. When I select `Formula evaluates to true` and then click on the `Insert Function` widget, I get no search results for even substring `CH`. Is the engine capable of evaluating such logic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See here is the Spring 15 release notes, the ISCHANGED() function is being deprecated, and now there is a function within the filter conditions that you must use.

http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_process_ischanged.htm

I have tested it out and indeed found the new 'is changed' option within the filter conditions.

Its a bit of a change as you no longer have to use a formula to use this functionality.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The formula function for determining whether a change occurred is ISCHANGED(). But, according to the Spring '15 release notes, this has been deprecated in Process Builder:

> It’s now easier in a process’s criteria to determine whether specific
>   fields on a record changed. We are deprecating the ISCHANGED formula
>   function and replacing it with the **Is changed** operator. This operator
>   is available for filter conditions.
>
> Existing active processes continue to work with the ISCHANGED formula
>   function, but you can’t clone the process. Similarly, you can’t make
>   changes to existing inactive processes that use the ISCHANGED formula
>   function. Instead, use the **Is changed** operator in a filter condition.

Here's a screenshot of how this would look.

[image]